# JS function triggering - how is my scope not right?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have this setup, it's not working because I suspect I messed up something in regards to scope?

(The wantToRunThis will be called by other events in addition to $someElement)

```
var wantToRunThis = function() {
... function code
};

$someElement.click(function() {
  wantToRunThis();
});
```

Comment: There's simply not enough cod here to determine what your issue is. What is the value of `$someElement`? Are you using the jQuery library? Have you checked the console for errors?

Comment: What m59 said, but here's a working example of your code which actually works in a window only scope: http://jsbin.com/ESIZuGAq/1/ - click the pinkish div.

Comment: To set it on global scope `window.wantToRunThis = function() {...}' BTW: `$someElement.click(wantToRunThis)`

Comment: my apologies, the scope was correct (like what you had limelights), it was mismatch in object naming... doh. Thank you all.